# Why does my NSTableView becomes blue when I select the header?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

What I select a column header of my `NSTableView` and none of my rows are selected, the column background becomes entirely blue:

[image]

What can I do to avoid this ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off column selection in the attributes inspector.